# Why does my Rails app break when I use image_tag to display a photo on Rails 6?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm currently taking an online course on Rails and I'm using the Carrierwave gem to have a photo uploading function on a test restaurant review site. When I type the following code:

```
<%= @review.photo %>
```

The output is:

```
/uploads/review/photo/12/aqua-roma-aqua-tokyo.jpg
```

However, when I add the `image_tag`

```
<%= image_tag @review.photo %>
```

The output gives me the following error:

**Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #PhotoUploader:0x00007fc684572ec8
Did you mean?  to_xml**

Comment: Is that value ever nil?  If you change it to `<%= image_tag @review.photo unless @review.photo.nil? %>` does it work?

Comment: @RockwellRice I tried that as well, but it didn't work and returns the same error. If I remove `image_tag` it displays the URL of the image, but returns an error when I add `image_tag` in front.

Answer (score 1):

With carrierwave, displaying image should be like

```
= image_tag( @review.photo.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add url to the image

```
 <%= image_tag @review.image.url %>
```